# Mobile Connect Reporting

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Does anyone have any information on what 'Culture Code *' is when creating Mobile Connect reports {{DisplayName_en-GB}} if sending from the UK, however I'm not exactly sure what this is.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a Salesforce bug - it should show the value as English United Kingdom i guess but is showing the templating value.
Open a ticket is best recourse. 
More generally, the culture code just changes how the data is formatted, for example yyyy-mm-did or mm-dd-yyyy date formats